# Decimal and special formatting in Java

Tags: java, formatting, numbers, format, decimal

I would like to convert my final double value 
i.e ( 1.0 ) 
to be printed out like $1.00. How is this possible in Java?

I imported java.lang.*
DecimalFormat formatter = new DecimalFormat("#.00");

Not sure how to get the dollar sign in there. I didn't know if there was any other way to do this aside from going "$" + .....

Comment: Can you show your codes (what have you tried)?

Answer (score 0):

Use [`String.format`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#format%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29):

```
// Format double with 2 decimal places and add a dollar sign
String price = "$" + String.format("%.2f", myDouble);
```

To print it directly, use [`PrintWriter.printf`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintWriter.html#printf%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object...%29), e.g. on `System.out`:

```
System.out.printf("$%.2f", myDouble);
```

Comment: Honestly, printf or NumberFormat is a more direct solution, ignoring that this question is a dup.

Comment: @BrianRoach Yes, thought about using `printf` first but changed it to `String.format` because it allows to use the value instead of just printing it. And, well, you *can* use `NumberFormat`, but I personally prefer simplicity. Thanks for your feedback :)

Answer (score 0):

Use `DecimalFormat`

```
    double value = 1.0;
    DecimalFormat dformat = new DecimalFormat("#.00");
    String modifiedVal = dformat.format(value);
    System.out.println("$"+modifiedVal);
```

Comment: Honestly, printf or NumberFormat is a more direct solution, ignoring that this question is a dup.

Comment: @BrianRoach : Thanks, came to know a new thing.. :)

Answer (score 0):

The [NumberFormat](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/NumberFormat.html) class has a pre-defined instance for currency formatting.

```
double value = 1.0;
NumberFormat nf = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance();
System.out.println(nf.format(value));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `Locale` & `NumberFormat` classes in Java.

```
NumberFormat formatter = NumberFormat.getCurrencyInstance(new Locale("en","US"));
System.out.println(formatter.format(1.0));
```